# Opensearch cluster can't allocate after deleting index

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, opensearch

##### Problem:

After deleting index all indices are in the red state and cluster allocation is stuck jumping between two states.

##### Preliminaries:

Split operation from index x (280gb 10mil documents 1shard) to index y that was expected to have 8shards. After execution split couldn't perform delete-by-query and index was jumping from 700gb to 1.3tb for a day, I made decision to delete that index and after that all indices are stuck in the red state.

##### Question:

What caused it? How it can be fixed?

###### Cluster details

Cluster managed with helm+kubernetes on aws (I can share instances details if needed) 
3 data, 3 master nodes 
1200gb disk attached to each data-node 
32gb ram data node, 8 gb master-node

Answer (score 0):

After deeper investigation, I realised that my data nodes probably stopped working correctly and I had to delete pods to force restart on them, after that cluster started operating normally